# Recover an Integrand from a Definite Integral

Tags: integration

Take $f(x)=x^2+2x+k$ and $V=\text{Integrate}[f(x),{x,0,1}]$ which gives the answer,$V=k + 4/3$.
Assuming I have no idea what $f(x)$ was, I was only given $V = k + 4/3$ with the limits of integration $[0,1]$ that produced $V$, is it possible to recover $f(x)$ from V?

Thanks

Comment: Any restrictions on $f$? Like, a polynomial of degree at most 2.

Comment: @lhf. Yes, a restriction on f(x), as a polynomial of degree 2 is presumed.

Comment: A solution is $f(x)=\frac 43+k$. Another is $81x^2-54x+2k(x+1)/3$.

Comment: Please add the restriction to the question.

Answer (score 1):

We can try to work in reverse and show that another integral will produce the same result when integrated with the same limits of integration.

Hence, if we try for example $f(x)=3x^8 + 5x^4 + k$:

$$\int_{0}^{1} 3x^8 + 5x^4 + k\: dx$$
$$=\frac{x^9}{3} +x^5 +kx \Big|_0^1 $$
$$=\frac{1}{3}+1+k = \frac{4}{3}+k$$

Proven by contradiction

And in general, any integral of $f(x)$ for $f(x) = \frac{a}{3}x^{a-1}+bx^{b-1}+k$ for $a,b>1$ when integrated from 0 to 1 will give you the same result as $\int_{0}^{1} x^2 + 2x + k\: dx$

Comment: @baryon. Thanks for your insight. It is true that other functions could produce the same value for V. Would it mean that additional constraints are needed to uniquely obtain the particular f(x) that produced V?

Comment: @D.Andrew many linear combinations can produce the same result. So having constraints on the number of terms, on the power of the terms and their coefficients could potentially allow you to obtain f(x) from the result of the integral. As long as the constraints on f(x) are sufficiently detailed to lead you to a single combination of terms, powers and coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot "invert" a definite integral because there are infinitely many functions that sum to zero in the given range.

This is only possible if you know the form of the integrand, with a single unknown parameter, so that you get one equation in one unknown.

---

A trivial solution is a constant function having as value the average, i.e. the ratio of the integral over the interval length.

---

In your case the value of the integral is a linear combination of two terms, and so is the integrand. Hence you have two (independent) inversion problems instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

If $$\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx=V$$ is given, **any integrable function** $g(x)$ such that

$$\int_0^1 g(x)\,dx\ne 0$$ can be used: let

$$h(x):=\frac{V}{\displaystyle\int_0^1 g(t)\,dt} g(x).$$

It is clear that $h(x)$ satifies the required condition.